# Rails - having a ajax button to make call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Say I have a button on my form, it doesn't submit the form, but it basically goes off to get some more information:

```
<%= f.button '', class:'hidden', id: 'do_calculation', remote: true %>
```

How do I tie this up so that when it is clicked it calls a controller action and returns the data?

Should I have something like this on the same page?

```
<script>
  function calculate_close() {
    var id = '<%= @thing.id %>';
    $.ajax({
      url: "<%= calculate_path %>",
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      dataType: "script"
    })
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can create a html button without using form builder like.

```
<button id="do_calculation">Button</button>
```

Then you can bind the click event to that button and call the ajax inside that event, like:

```
$("#do_calculation").on('click', function(){
  var id = '<%= @thing.id %>';
  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= calculate_path %>",
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    dataType: "json"
  })
})
```

and in the controller you can use something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => {:message => "success"} }
end
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: any example of using a button_to?  and how do I handle the respond_to in the controller action?

Comment: to create button you can use button_tag here is the link for that, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag